# A question about the scanf() and whitespace

Tags: c, scanf

I am a novice in C, (just started learning it), so please do not pay much attention to my ignorance.

To the question now. It regards the use of `[^\n]` in `scanf()` (following the example of my study book). Nevertheless it seems that it does not work at all.

Thank you in advance.

The following snippet, when compiled, prints nothing (if the user enters a string with white-spaces). Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char str[100];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[˄\n]", str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Thus, e.g., if the user enters `This is a text` it outputs nothing! On the other hand, without `[^\n]`, it does print the string up to the first white-space.

Comment: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer) is worth a read. You may want to use `" %[^\n]"`to skip leading whitespace. Important if you ever mix this with `"%d"` and such so you don't end up with an empty string.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: if the previous input call was a `scanf("%d", ...)`, you don't end up with an empty string, `scanf("%[^\n]", ...)` instead returns `0` and leaves `str` unchanged, hence uninitialized! Not necessarily an empty string.  Always check the return value of `scanf()`.  As a matter of fact, `scanf("%[^\n]", ...)` cannot read an empty string even if the enter key is hit immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character you typed in the format string is not the ASCII caret symbol, it is a Unicode circumflex accent `˄` U+02C4 encoded in UTF-8 as the 2 bytes [CB 84]. The format string is hence `%[\xCB\x84\n]` so `scanf()` only accepts a sequence of any combination of these 3 bytes.

If the user inputs anything else as the first character, `scanf()` will return `0` after the user hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  Conversely, if the user hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the `\n` is accepted and input continues until a character different from the 3 bytes is entered, but which will only be made available if the user hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key another time.

The observed behavior is the input continues as long as only the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is typed and multiple newlines are then output, those in `str` followed by a final newline.

You probably typed the circumflex accent on your keyboard (possibly a French [AZERTY](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) or similar layout) followed by a space instead of the <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> key combination.

There are other problems with the `%[^\n]` format:

- there is no way for `scanf()` to find the length of the destination array, and any sufficiently long input will cause a buffer overflow.  You should write `%99[^\n]`.
- if the user enters an empty line by hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, `scanf()` will return `0`, leaving the buffer `str` unchanged, hence uninitialized.
- if the input stream is empty, `scanf()` will return `EOF`, also without modifying the buffer `str`.
- the newline entered by the user is left pending in the input stream, potentially causing confusing behavior for subsequent inputs using `scanf()` or `fgets()`.

Therefore you should always test the return value of `scanf()` to detect and report invalid or missing input instead of invoking undefined behavior, and it is less confusing to use `fgets()` to read strings from the user.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char str[100];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (scanf("%99[^\n]", str) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    } else {
        printf("invalid or missing input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a recommended approach to input a string from the user using `fgets()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char str[101];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline if any
        printf("%s\n", str);
    } else {
        printf("cannot read from input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most obliged for you kind and detailed answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You use the wrong symbol `˄`. The correct one is the one from the ASCII character set: `^`. This typically happens if something (e.g. an Internet site or a keyboard) applied auto-correct on the code, thinking it's text.

Some compilers output a warning if they see suspicious characters in your code. Please heed these warnings! Unfortunately, some compilers just say "your code has a bad character" and don't say which one and where.